# Total voltage of six 12V batteries in line

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power

Total voltage of six 12V batteries in-line

A golf cart has six 12V flooded batteries in line.  Each battery has six cells (six flooded holes for maintaining levels with distilled water.)  Each hole or cell is 2V and the battery is rated as 12V (2V x 6 cells = 12V.)  The in-line or series of 6 batteries would mean the total voltage is 72V for the system or golf cart.

If this is correct, all support components, battery charger, etc., would also have to be rated as 72V systems.

Is this correct?

Comment: Adding the info about the 12V batteries having 2V cells confuses the question. Essentially, you are saying there are 6x 12V batteries in series, yes? Can you clear that up and just make the question a bit clearer?

Comment: voltages add when batteries are connected in series ... same as the voltages of cells in a battery

Answer (score 6):

More or less. Actually, the battery voltage is probably more like 14.4V under charge, which results in 86V for the series string. Add in some engineering margin and it would be reasonable to make sure that everything is 100V tolerant, or better.

But yes, that's called a "72V system".

Comment: Is such a 72V system really commonly used? As far as I’m aware the safety limit for DC voltage in many situations is as low as 60V. Hence why many systems try to stay at or below a nominal 48V voltage (e.g. “mild hybrid” cars).

Comment: @Michael "... activity now with the standards groups about where the shock hazards lie. Certainly there are some 72 volts in the Neighborhood Electrics today that are absolutely, in my opinion, a hazard." "In the golf car environment you bring a car in off the golf course where it may be wet and you reach in there and grab something underneath with exposed live parts, a certain hazard does exist. Certainly the higher the voltage system goes the more hazard exposure." [Craig Journey, Former E-Z-GO Engineer](https://golfcar.blog/craig-journey-former-e-z-go-engineer/) - an interesting read.

Comment: Craig Journey says: "The National Electric Code now has two numbers, 30 volts wet and 60 volts dry".

Answer (score 5):

Not necessarily correct, depending what "in line" means:

1. Batteries in series or in parallel. You can connect all six 12V batteries in parallel and get a single 12V battery with 6 times the ampere-hour rating. Or connect them in series and get a single 72V battery. Or combine them creatively and make a 24V or 36V battery.
2. What yo say as 12V, 24V, 36V or 72V battery is a "nominal voltage". At the end of the charging, a nominal 12V battery is actually between 14 and 15 volt. A 72V battery could go as high as 90V.

Answer (score 0):

Some 12 V lead acid battery chargers for flooded lead acid batteries have what is called an "equalization" stage. In the equalization stage, the charger can put out as high as 15.5 V for a 12 V battery. If you extrapolate that to a "72" volt battery it works out to 93 V.

So, if you have a "72 Volt" lead acid battery connected to a charger, depending on the charger, the voltage could be as high as 93 V. Just FYI.